# counting permutations with conditions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Given the set $S = {1,2,3,4}$, how many ways can I make $w = (x_i,x_2,...,x_N)$ such that $x_i \in S$ with a rule that m 1's appear before k 2's in a word of length N?

For example if m=2, k=3 then I want to know how many words of length N have the form $(..,1,..1,..,2,..,2,2,..)$.

I have already tried brute forcing the solution using a computer, but with $4^N$ possibilities to check this quickly becomes untenable.

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find anything helpful searching.

Clarification: The full problem I am considering is looking for sequences which at some point $m-k > r$ and in the full final sequence $m+k > d$, but I think and answer to the initial question would give me some more insight to figure this out.

Comment: From the example you give it appears that you want all the $1's$ to appear before the $2's$ start.  So $(1,2,2,1,2)$ would not be a good example.  Is this correct?  Also:  do you want exactly $m$ $1's$ or would it be ok if there are more than $m$?

Comment: @lulu yes, I want the 1's to appear before the 2's start so (1,2,2,1,2) is not a good example. Hmm, I'm not 100% sure if more than $m$ would work with what I am trying to do. I am trying to count the number of combinations such that at some point in the sequence $m-k>r_1$ and that in the full sequence $m+k > d$.

Comment: Also, after the $k^{th}$ $2$ appears, can more $1's$ and/or $2's$ follow?  That is, is $(1,1,2,2,2,1,2)$ a good example?

Comment: more 1's and 2's can follow as long as there are equal numbers of them or more 2's than 1's. but if you can solve the case for exactly m 1's and k 2's I can code a loop over the possible combinations of m and k that meet my condition

Comment: Ok, let's say exactly $m$ and $k$.  Makes life a lot simpler. I'll post something below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments:  we are assuming that, amongst the $n$ symbols in our list, we get exactly $m$ $1'$ and exactly $k$ $2's$ and that all the $1$'s precede the first $2$.

In that case, all we need to do is to choose $m+k$ slots ($\binom {n}{m+k}$ ways to do that).

Then there is a unique way to populate those slots (the $1's$ come first, then the $2's$).

then we need to populate the remaining $n-m-k$ slots each with $3$ or $4$. (there are $2^{n-m-k}$ ways to do that).

putting it all together we see that there are $$\binom {n}{m+k}\,2^{n-m-k}$$ ways to make lists of your type.